# How to change the working directory of all the panes in a tmux window

Tags: unix, tmux

In using tmux, I generally like to keep each window dedicated to a specific service that I'm working on. I try to minimize the number of windows that I have open and so I don't want to just keep a window permanently open for each project that I find myself working on.

What I'd like is a way to set the working directory of every pane within my current window at once (rather than having to call `cd` from within each and every pane) - So that I can switch projects more easily instead of having to iterate over each pane to set the working directory

Comment: "rather than having to call `cd` from within each and every pane" – Without a debugger a process cannot change the working directory of another process. If there is already a shell in a pane, the only way to change its working directory without a debugger is to let the shell *itself* change the directory. You can either run a shell (or another process) anew in the right directory in the pane, or inject a `cd` command as if you are typing, so the old shell changes its working directory (if the shell happens to be in the foreground at the time). Do you want to bulk inject a `cd` command then?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski bulk injecting the command would definitely be acceptable for my use case. I'm mainly just trying to avoid having to manually do the navigation and typing of the `cd` command, rather than avoiding the `cd` command itself

Comment: [How to send a command to all panes in `tmux`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16325449/10765659).